# How to use other shortcodes inside Contact form 7- forms?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, shortcode

I noticed that any shortcode that is not part of the contact form 7 builtin shortcodes dont work.

For example: I am trying to use an accordion shortcode between form elements in contact form 7. But the code dont work.

How to solve this without editing contact form 7 core files?

Comment: Not sure that you can do this. Shortcodes have to be in a page or post, don't they. I don't think you can put a shortcode between form elements. Where would you put them? ... in the contact form 7 settings? You cant do that there AFAIK ( unless you're following some contact form 7 instructions I haven't heard of).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's two ways to do what you're wanting.  First way is to add this code to functions.php of the Contact Form 7 plugin:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements' );

function mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) {
$form = do_shortcode( $form );

return $form;
}
```

That allows you to drop shortcodes directly into CF7.  Second is to add the Accordion in manually with HTML in the contact form, like this:

```
<!-- begin class .wp-accordion -->
<div class="wp-accordion wpui-light">

    <!-- First tab's panel -->
    <h3 class="wp-tab-title">Tab 1</h3>
    <!-- First tab's contents -->
    <div class="wp-tab-content">
          All the contents of first tab goes here....
    </div><!-- end first tab -->

      <!-- Like so, Second panel -->
      <h3 class="wp-tab-title">Tab 2</h3>
      <div class="wp-tab-content">
            Contents of the second tab
       </div>

</div><!-- end class wp-accordion -->
```

I think the second method is preferable, since there is no modifying of core plugin files.  I hope this helps out!

Comment: Actually - you can add the filter code in your theme's functions.php and shortcodes will work properly inside a CF7 form. I can't confirm whether the specific one(for the accordion) will work or not though - I've only tested with a shortcode that doesn't contain any CF7 shortcodes, but basically it all depends on how the shortcode in question is handled.

Comment: indeed, a simple `add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode' );` does the trick from my child theme's functions.php.

Comment: If you want to use the same content in more than one location on your site, you're better off creating a shortcode (localizable if necessary), than to cut and paste the same HTML all over the place.

Comment: I have used this code but it is not working, so can you please help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359534/my-shortcode-is-not-working-in-contact-form-7-message-body