# other shortcodes in Contact form 7 MAILS

Tags: shortcode, forms, contact, email

[How to use other shortcodes inside Contact form 7- forms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/how-to-use-other-shortcodes-inside-contact-form-7-forms) indeed explains how to use other shortcodes inside Contact Form 7 forms. But that doesn't make them usable in the mails that Contact Form 7 sends on submission of the form. How do I make them work there too?

Answer (score 0):

WPCF7 incorporates more filters than used in the answer you already found.

Analogously to that, the `wpcf7_posted_data` filter should do what you are looking for:

```
function wpse73667_wpcf7_posted_data( $posted_data )
{
    $posted_data = do_shortcode( $posted_data );
    return $posted_data;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'wpse73667_wpcf7_posted_data' );
```

Note that this is an educated guess and untested.

You can find all the filters available by searching the `%plugins_directory%/contact-form-7/includes/classes.php` file for the term `apply_filters`.